# Write a program that receives a number from the input and finds the first two prime numbers after it in c++

Tags: c++

The task was: Write a program that receives a number from the input and finds the first two prime numbers after it in c++.

I tried

```
#include <iostream>

// Check, if a number is prime and return true, if it is
bool isPrime(int value) {

    bool isPrime = true;
    // Try all potential values
    for (int i = 2; i <= value / 2; ++i) {
        if (value % i == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isPrime;
}

int main() {
    // Read start value, check, if in OK range
    if (int number{}; (std::cin >> number) and (number > 3))
    {
        int primeCounter = 0;
        // Check for the next 2 prime values
        while (primeCounter < 2) {
            if (isPrime(number)) {
                // Prime found
                std::cout << number << '\n';
                ++primeCounter;
            }
            // Try next number
            ++number;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "The input value is not ok\n";
    }
}
```

But the answer was judged as wrong. What could be the reason?

Thank you for your kindness and help!

Comment: Start with writing a function that determines whether a given number is a prime number.

Comment: What do you expect if you enter a prime number and what does your code produce? Why are you not allowing the user to enter anything below 4? Your isPrime deems 1 to be a prime but it is definitionally excluded from the series of prime numbers. Also: When your code was "judged as wrong" (by whom? what?), what was the reason given?

Comment: Here's a huge hint to make your program faster.  Special case "2" and only check for odd numbers.

Answer (score 0):

There are only some minor issues with the code:

The prime check function was not optimized. It worked, but now it is a little bit faster. But does not matter taht much.

The input range check was wrong and, because you wanted to have the primes after the input value. So one increment is necessary.

The corrected code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

// Check, if a number is prime and return true, if it is
bool isPrime(int value) {

    // Special cases
    if (value < 2) return false;
    if (value == 2) return true;
    if (value % 2 == 0) return false;
    // Brute force
    bool isPrime = true;
    // Try all potential values
    for (int i = 3; i*i < value / 2; i+=2) {
        if (value % i == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isPrime;
}

int main() {
    // Read start value, check, if in OK range
    if (int number{}; (std::cin >> number) and (number > 0))
    {
        // need the next folowing 2 prime numbers
        ++number;

        int primeCounter = 0;
        // Check for the next 2 prime values
        while (primeCounter < 2) {
            if (isPrime(number)) {
                // Prime found
                std::cout << number << '\n';
                ++primeCounter;
            }
            // Try next number
            ++number;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "The input value is not ok\n";
    }
}
```